# Unable to setup port-forwarding through Dynamic DNS (DDNS)

Tags: networking, router, dns, ip, port-forwarding

I am trying to enable the ability to connect to my router from outside my network through a Dynamic DNS and I am stuck on port forwarding.

I have setup a Dynamic DNS through my router with url `X.ddns.net`. When I do `nslookup X.ddns.net`, I see the url directs to address `10.0.X.X`. This also happens to look identical to if I went to 192.168.1.1 (the router login page). I am able to ping `X.ddns.net` from inside my network but not from outside.

Now I want to setup port forwarding. The router expects a Device IP of the form `192.168.X.X`. However, `10.0.X.X` is not the correct form and it says `192.168.1.1` is an invalid IP.

The Dynamic DNS provider provides a tool to check if port forwarding is enabled. It also seems to think `10.0.X.X` should be the IP used for port forwarding.

How do I find the Device IP I am supposed to use to enable port forwarding over my Dynamic DNS?

---

**Edit:**

The feedback so far has been really helpful. In this edit I try to respond to the questions asked and clarify my language based on my reading of the issue and some updates.

I am able to realize two possible scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** I can have the router be responsible for updating `X.ddns.net`. Though this works locally, the IP pointed to is private (being 10.0.X.X) and therefore is not accessible outside on the network. I can port forward locally but not from outside my network.

**Scenario 2:** I can have my Ubuntu system update `X.ddns.net`. This uses a public IP (73.174.X.X) and therefore can be accessed locally and from outside my network. However, I am not able to port forward through this port even with my firewall and filters turned off.

For port forwarding, I go to my router settings at 192.168.1.1. I enable port forwarding for my Device IP (192.168.X.X for NoMachine), from port Y to port Y. This partially works for setup 1 (described above), but only locally. Port forwarding does not work in setup 2.

Example Router Port Forward Config:

```
Application Name    External Port   Internal port   To IP address   Protocol
NoMachine           29383           4000            192.168.1.93    both
```

Within my network and from outside my network, nslookup gives the same result for scenario 1 (where DDNS points to private IP) and scenario 2 (where DDNS points to public IP).

I am connecting my Linksys WRT3200ACM to an Xfinity Gateway (Arris TG3482G), and doing my work on the Linksys router. Could this be an issue? I'm not sure if this answers your WAN question, but I observe the following in both scenarios.

```
$ route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.X.X         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enoX
169.254.X.X     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 enoX
172.106.X.X     192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 enoX
192.168.X.X     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 enoX
```

For `nslookup X.ddns.net`, scenario 1, I observe the following...

```
# LOCAL NETWORK
Server:     127.0.0.X
Address:    127.0.0.X#X

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   X.ddns.net
Address: 10.0.X.X

# FROM OUTSIDE OF NETWORK
Server:     172.20.X.X
Address:    172.20.X.X#X

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   X.ddns.net
Address: 10.0.X.X
```

For scenario 2, it looks like this...

```
# LOCAL NETWORK
Server:     127.0.X.X
Address:    127.0.X.X#X

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   X.ddns.net
Address: 73.174.X.X

# FROM OUTSIDE OF NETWORK
Server:     172.20.X.X
Address:    172.20.X.X#X

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   X.ddns.net
Address: 73.174.X.X
```

Is there anything else I should check to narrow down the issue?

Comment: Please compare your router's public IP address as reported by its web interface with the IP address one of the "what's my IP" services show. Are they the same? // Your router may have problems with hairpin NAT. To reliable test your setup, you must do so from outside your local network (e.g. on your cell phone with Wi-Fi disabled).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, your router is behind some form of Carrier-grade NAT. (Well, or maybe the NAT of your another router that it is connected to, albeit less likely.) In other words, your ISP does not offer you a public IP that is solely for your use.

The DDNS client on your router simply notifies its server about the WAN address of your router, and neither of them checks whether it's from any of the private IP blocks.

Therefore, your only hope to "expose" your LAN host to the Internet is to set up a VPN server on some VPS host that has its own public IP, make your LAN host join the VPN, and port forward on the VPN server.

Comment: You can confirm my deduction by checking the WAN address shown on your router's admin page. You should see it being the `10.0.X.X`.

Comment: @Joseph this is the more likely scenario than what I had assumed. If Carrier-grade NAT is involved, then dynamic DNS isn't an option.

Comment: @Joseph just saw your edits. If nslookup is giving `10.0.X.X` from outside your network, and your Linksys router is the only router in question (hooked up to the Arris modem/gateway) then it definitely sounds like your ISP is using carrier-grade NAT :(

Comment: Does it help if I use a dynamic DNS update client on one of my computers (i.e. scenario 2), or is this a fundamental limitation of the CGNAT? I added the nslookup...

Comment: `nslookup` only tells what the DDNS client have "reported" to the server, and most likely it would be the WAN address of the router if the client is ran on one. (If the client runs from a LAN host, most likely it would be do some kind of what-is-my-ip probing and report the real Internet/public address to the server, regardless of whether the host is behind any NAT.) These does not really tell you whether you are behind carrier-grade NAT, given the fact that you have an "outer" "modem-but-also-router". To confirm whether you are, you should check the WAN address shown on the admin page there.

Comment: I can confirm that the WAN on the Xfinity Router/Modem is the same as what is shown in Scanrio 2 -- 73.174.X.X...

Comment: @Joseph If you confirm that you are not behind CGNAT, most likely you should configure either router to work in bridge mode (which to configure depends on e.g. whether you need the outer one to work as an WiFi AP). If the outer router is made to work in bridge mode, you should be able to run the DDNS client on the inner router, since its WAN IP will be the public IP (if no carrier-grade NAT). If the inner one is made to work in bridge mode, then you probably need to either run the client on a LAN host.

Comment: @Joseph Port forwarding will need to be configured on the outer one if the inner one is made to work in bridge mode btw. Also to clarify, if you made the outer one work in bridge mode, then you should also disable its wireless feature and connect nothing but the inner router to it, since many ISPs only allow you to get one public IP from it.

Comment: @Joseph `If the inner one is made to work in bridge mode, then you probably need to either run the client on a LAN host.` That was written with the assumption that the outer router does not have the required DDNS client/support on it btw.

Comment: Bridging the connection fixed it, and I can now port forward through the DDNS managed by the router (scenario 1)! Scenario 2 also works without bridging if port forwarding is enabled on the Router/Modem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple unknowns here:

1. On your network, which machine is responsible for updating `X.ddns.net` whenever your ISP-assigned public IP address changes? Some routers support it directly on the router itself. If your router doesn't, then another always-on machine in your network will be responsible for this task.
2. How is port forwarding being handled? Did you manually set a `*:publicPort -> privateIp:privatePort` association? Or is some bit of software handling that? It sounds like you tried to set up a port forward manually on the router, but the router told you it was invalid (and I think I know why, if you read on).
3. When you do an `nslookup`, are you doing that from within your network? I assume that you are, given that it is returning a `10.0.0.0/8` address. If you did a lookup outside your network, then you should see a public IP address, not a private one.

   1. Assuming you did the `nslookup` from within your network, I'll make an assumption that the dynamic dns update client is on the router itself, your hosts are querying the router for DNS records, and the router has been configured to perform split-horizon DNS, telling local clients the `10.0.0.0/8` address so that they need not go out to the internet and right back in.
   2. I'd normally assume that the router's dynamic DNS software was also handling the port forwarding directly, but since you've said you tried to set it yourself, I won't.

**And here is the tricky bit**:

Dynamic DNS is usually meant to grant access to a host **behind the router** (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnae2J3DAlY), not to the router **itself**. For example, if you had an nginx or apache webserver running on the `10.0.X.X` host on your local network, and had set up port forwarding on the router, then visitors on the internet could see that server's web pages if they went to `X.ddns.net`.

However, you aren't wanting to hop to a host behind the router. You want to get on the router **itself**. In theory, you don't need port forwarding for that. Indeed, you've said that when you visit the `10.0.X.X` address on your local network, it looks exactly like the `192.168.1.1` address, which tells me that `10.0.X.X` is the IP address of the router in the `10.0.0.0/8` subnet. That is, `10.0.X.X` **is not the private/internal IP address of a host on your network; it's an IP address for the router**. The port forwarding you attempted to set up was invalid because it was basically saying "forward traffic from the router to the router."

In this case, you might be able to access the router externally merely by visiting `X.ddns.net`. Your router would need to allow external traffic on port 80, and at that point, your router's login page would be available on `X.ddns.net` to you on the internet (and to **everyone else** on the internet, too). Seeing as there probably isn't an SSL/TLS certificate on the router, that means that your username and password for the router would be visible in plaintext to anyone between you and the router when you visit `X.ddns.net` from outside your network. You don't want this.

**So what is there to do?**

At a minimum, it might be possible to set up a proxy on a host within your network (**behind** the router), which can have a (self-signed) SSL/TLS certificate for accepting connections from the external internet, and then forward the traffic in plaintext, on your local network, to the router and back to the proxy (which would then go back through the router and to the external client on the internet). In this scenario, your login credentials to the router are protected and can't be snooped on by third-parties. In this scenario, this proxy host is the one that is assigned the `10.0.X.X` IP address (and it shouldn't be the router's `10.0.X.X` IP address; it should be a different one).

But setting this up is a non-trivial effort, and would require a self-signed SSL/TLS certificate since you likely don't have authority to craft one for `X.ddns.net`. So, you'd have to manually bypass the self-signed certificate alerts in your browser when going to `X.ddns.net` from outside your network.

If your router has built-in support for remote entry, I'd definitely use that before undertaking the above-mentioned proxy effort.

---

One more aside:

Introducing a second private subnet, `10.0.0.0/8`, in addition to the one that, it sounds like, already exists, `192.168.1.0/24`, needlessly adds complication IMHO. Instead of introducing `10.0.0.0/8`, use the existing `192.168.1.0/24` subnet and pick a different IP address in the subnet for the proxy host.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, these are good questions. I revised my post to help clarify. I'm also still digesting your feedback on the tricky bit...